How to encode 2 bytes (stored in an int2) to a 16-bit float (half) in HLSL?
I have a function which converts 4 bytes (stored in an int4 with a range of 0-255) to a 32-bit float, in HLSL. It works great:
inline float UnpackFloatRGBA(int4 bytes)
    {
        int sign = (bytes.r & 128) > 0 ? -1 : 1;
        int expR = (bytes.r & 127) << 1;
        int expG = bytes.g >> 7;
        int exponent = expR + expG;
        int signifG = (bytes.g & 127) << 16;
        int signifB = bytes.b << 8;
        float significand = (signifG + signifB + bytes.a) / pow(2, 23);
        significand += 1;
        return sign * significand * pow(2, exponent - 127);
    }

However, I also need to convert 2 bytes (stored in an int2) to a half, in HLSL. How would I go about adapting the above function for that purpose? I don't know enough about the magic of floating point bit shifting to figure out it...
